# Light junction box near water

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture, junction-box

We are wanting to put in sconce lighting in our bedroom. The junction box would be about 16 inches form our water shut off valves and bleed valves. Is there any issues about putting the lights in this proximity of the water valves?

[image]

The light will be install on the right side of the wall, which is over the bed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any direct issues here.

However, to prevent any issues in a "what-if" scenario where the valve springs a high pressure (spraying) leak: 
For the junction box in the wall, have the wires enter the box from the bottom, and have the wire form a "U" loop at the bottom.  This way, if there ever is some kind of spraying leak from the valve (unlikely) that any water that gets onto the NM jacket would drip off at the bottom of the "U" loop and not run into the junction box.  If you have the wire running in from the top of the box, its possible that in a leak situation the water on the NM cable could drip into the junction box which would be very bad.

Make sure the box is installed correctly, with the NM jacket coming just into the box.